# Flaw with proving that $S$ is a basis of $V$ iff $\|v\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{c_i}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with a positive-definite scalar product $(\cdot,\cdot)$. Let $S = \left\lbrace v_1,...,v_n \right\rbrace$ be a set of orthogonal vectors of unit length in $V$ and $c_i =(v,v_i), \quad i=1,...n$ be the associated Fourier coefficients. 
Prove that $S$ is a basis for $V$ if and only if $$\|v\|^2=(v,v)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{c_i}^2, \quad \forall v \in V$$

Attempt: 
If $S$ is a basis of $V$, then $\forall v \in V$ $$v = a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$$ and $$c_i = (v,v_i)=(a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n,v_i) = a_i$$ $$\therefore \|v\|^2=(v,v)=(a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n,a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{c_i}^2$$

Conversely, if $$\|v\|^2=(v,v)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{c_i}^2, \quad \forall v \in V$$ we need to show that $v_i$ are linearly independent. To this end, consider $$b_1v_1+...+b_nv_n=0$$ $$\therefore (b_1v_1+...+b_nv_n,b_1v_1+...+b_nv_n) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}{b_i}^2= 0$$ $$\therefore b_i = 0$$ One can also show, by the same argument presented before, that $$b_i=c_i$$

My question is, does the above argument suffice or is there any flaw with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the second direction (i.e., assuming that $\|v\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v,v_i \rangle^2$ for all $v \in V$), all you've proved is that $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, but this is a general fact about orthogonal sets proved by precisely your argument. The essential point is proving that $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ *spans* $V$. So, let $v \in V$, define
$$
 v_0 := \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\langle v_i,v\rangle}{\langle v_i,v_i\rangle} v_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_i,v\rangle v_i, \quad v_1 := v - v_0,
$$
and observe that $v = v_0 + v_1$ with $\langle v_0,v_1 \rangle = 0$; what you need to show is that $v_1 = 0$. But then, $$\|v\|^2 = \langle v,v \rangle = \langle v_0+v_1,v_0+v_1\rangle,$$ so what do you get when you expand out $\langle v_0+v_1,v_0+v_1 \rangle$?

Comment: I understand proving $S$ spans $V$. However, wouldn't $n$ linearly independent vectors form a basis for $V$? So that it would be sufficient to prove that they are linearly independent?

Comment: Absolutely, but only if you're given that $V$ is $n$-dimensional.